# Configuring Barnyard2 Output Plug-In Per Input Source

Tags: monitoring, snort, barnyard2

I am currently using snort-2.9.3.1 outputting unified2 log format and using barnyard2-1.9 to process the alerts and send them to both syslog and a database. In some cases I have multiple instances of snort running on the same host and would like to log them separately.

Is there a way to configure barnyard2 such that depending on the input file name it will take different actions.

Something like,

```
 [snortmain_unified.log]
 output alert_syslog: LOG_AUTH LOG_ALERT

 [snortsecondary_unified.log
 output alert_syslog: LOG_LOCAL1 LOG_ERR
```

I am hoping to avoid running multiple instances of barnyard2.